# Valid joomla language file not loaded

Tags: joomla

I've created a valid Joomla translation file, but when I switch on the language debug, the file is listed as "**not loaded**"

Contents of language file:

```
; Joomla! Project
; Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
; License GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt, see LICENSE.php
; Note : All ini files need to be saved as UTF-8 - No BOM

CATEGORIZED_IN="Categorized In"
```

Just simple ini file stuff. Dont think there are any errors.

Here's the debug output:
[image: you can see the script is not loaded]

Comment: Double check if the file on your server is really that one and has the content you have posted here. And also if it has the right folder permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the name of the language file in the template.xml was different! Thanks @Laoneo for pointing out my stupidity. Must have happened during the Joomla 2.5 -> 3.2 update when the template name was automatically changed.

Comment: Yep also had a problem with naming. I had a string in the name like 'tml.MyAlert.ini' but Joomla was looking for 'tml.myalert.ini'. So it doesn't accept capitalized letters.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the language file had a few `<<<<<<< HEAD` and `======` due to a botched conflict resolution and subsequent merge, so please make sure the language file doesn't have any such issue otherwise it will just silently be ignored.